# ORA-00905 on Join with Select

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables that I am trying to join - users and accesshist.

Columns in users:  `lastname, firstname, username`

Columns in accesshist:  `usernameattempted, loginattemptdate, isloginsuccessful`.

The username in users should match the usernameattempted in accesshist and the isloginsuccessful is boolean.

I am looking to find a list of users and if they recently successfully logged in - the date of that attempt.

Here is what I have:

```
select ll.mxlogin, ll.usernameattempted, u.username
from users u
inner join (select max(loginattemptdate) as mxlogin, usernameattempted from accesshist where isloginsuccessful=1 group by usernameattempted) as ll 
on u.username = ll.usernameattempted;
```

And when I run it, I am getting the following error:
ORA-00905: missing keyword

Not sure what I am doing wrong....any pointers are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Oracle does not support `as` for table aliases. Replace `as ll` with `ll`

Comment: Thank you!  That was it.  Thought that I had tried that earlier, but obviously not.

Comment: Note to the folks who voted to close this question on the grounds that it was "caused by a typo" or "an error that cannot be reproduced." Such causes do **not** apply to this question. It is a frequently asked question, and you may vote to close it for being a duplicate; but the errant AS is a syntax error, it is not a typo; and the error absolutely **can** be reproduced, easily: just add the illegal keyword AS between an inline view definition or table name and its alias, and you will get the same error. And the answer **will** help others in the future, who have the same question.